# For each div tag, take its contents

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to loop through the code of a HTML page and reformat it's contents. It has a few div's within div's, which I want to extract. I've tried various forms of explode, regex and DOM, but can't find exactly how to do this.

Example:

```
<div class="section1">
 <div class="section2">number 1</div>
</div>
<div class="section1">
 <div class="section2">number 2</div>
</div>
```

The result I'm looking for is basically, for each section 1, get contents from section 2, so the output would be:
        number 1, number 2

Does anyone know how to do something like this?

Comment: DOM would arguably be the best way of doing it. Could you post the code you tried with DOM and we can have a look to see where it went awry?

Comment: When you say output, where are outputting too and reading from? Are you trying to actively parse a live website, or just reading in a script offline?

Comment: javascript is the only **right** way to do this.

Comment: also tell the reason so if other user know the better solution /approach they will tell you

Comment: do you want to do it client side using javascript or on server side using php??

Comment: @Fluffeh Unofrtunately I can't post the exact copde, as I tried many, many variations, but can't really find where to insert the loop (for each div tag of this name, get the contents of the div tag with that name).

Comment: @Zeritor I am reading from a HTML file, and outputting to a PHP variable, which I can then add to a database. I've downloaded a series of HTML files for which I need to do this.

Comment: @RegisteredUser The reason is I am trying to re-format sports scores from a tabel-type lay-out to a single line.

Comment: @Surace I'd like to do it server side using PHP

Answer (score 3):

Should be pretty easy with [`DOMXPath`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML(/*...*/); // load the HTML here
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$result = $xpath->query("//div[@class='section1']/div[@class='section2']/text()");

foreach ($result as $item) {
    echo "$item->wholeText\n";
}
```

[**See it in action**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KE77pA).

Comment: I will give this a try later today, thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

This is a **jQuery** solution, not **PHP**:

```
$('.section1).each(function() {
    return $(this).html();
});
```

Comment: ops sorry !! I will delete it, but I think that the Javascript solution is the only one...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have enough JAvaScript knowledge to really try this at the moment, but I am planning to learn it at some point. Thank you for your answer!